# Possible to prevent XCode from envoking debugger after calling `XCUIApplication().terminate()`

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I'm using UITest for testing an objective C app, using swift for the tests.

XCode 7.3, sim 9.3

Every test case invokes XCUIApplication.launch(), which kills any running application by sending SIGKILL.

Xcode treats this like a crash - invoking the debugger on `main.m`. To proceed with the test suite I just click the continue button in the debugger.

After hitting continue, my log says:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```

This situation is frustrating because it happens after 1/4 of my test cases. Causing me to lose focus on the document I'm editing and causing my test suite to hang until I hit continue.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: While not a direct solution, you could always turn off breakpoints with ⌃⌘Y or delete/disable the exception breakpoint.

Comment: @JoeMasilotti Which breakpoint are you suggesting I delete? XCode's breakpoint manager (⌘7) shows "No Breakpoints". It seems to be a "built in" behavior. Event after disabling breakpoints system wide as you suggested (⌘Y), I still get dumped into my debugger just as frequently between UITest restarts.

Comment: Do you do tearDown() after test case?

Comment: @Che - You shouldn't have to as launchApp() will kill the app if it's already running. But also - yes, I've tried that, and saw no measurable difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We experienced the same issue. After some debugging we found out this was caused by having `Background Modes` enabled for your app.

Our solution was to make a new target for development and testing that has all `Background Modes` disabled.

FYI, in the `Capabilities` section of your project settings it's labeled as `Background Modes` turning this `Off` is key.  Alternatively, you could remove the `Require background modes` (aka `UIBackgroundModes`) key from your Info.plist

Comment: This also fixes asserts on XCUIApplication().launch() "UI Testing Failure - Failure attempting to launch".

Answer (score 0):

You can go for debugging and/or testing after termination using xCode. In the menu:

1. Debug
2. Attach to Process
3. Choose from `Likely Targets` or `By Process Identifier (PID)`