# Xcode UI tests don't automatically launch simulator

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, xcuitest, uitest

Usually when Xcode starts a UI test, it will automatically launch the selected simulator first.

I have a project in which this is broken: if the simulator is not already open, I get this error:

"No devices are booted."

[image: No devices are booted error screenshot]

- This occurs before the test `setup()` function is called.
- If the simulator is already open, everything works as normal.
- It is local to one specific project and persists if I make a new UI test target in that project
- The problem does not happen if I make a new project with a new UI test bundle - the simulator launches as per normal.
- I'm using Xcode 10.2 and have tried resetting simulators as well as reinstalling them.
- It inteferes with running UI tests in parallel as clones do not launch automatically.

Does anyone know what this could be related to?

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue with a project, and it's because we have a "Reset Simulator" build phase with this shell script:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall booted your.bundle.identifier
```

I found the source of the problem by looking at the very top of the build error message and seeing what triggered the error. In my case, it happened with "Run custom shell script 'Reset Simulator'" which led me to the phase/script causing it: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJcth.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the simulator using

1. Hardware -> Erase All Contents And Settings.
2. If that does not help, I think you can check to see if the below might help

   xcrun simctl erase all
   // Specifying all will erase all existing devices.
   "Erase a device's contents and settings.
   Usage: simctl erase  [... ] | all"

Can you also add what version of the Xcode you are using?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem that easy! It's persisted through resetting, deleting and reinstalling the simulators, and upgrading Xcode, on two machines. I'm now using Xcode 10.2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409060/possible-to-prevent-xcode-from-envoking-debugger-after-calling-xcuiapplication

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413059/intermittent-failure-attempting-to-launch-in-ios-uitest

Comment: Try those two posts, may be you are doing something similar the ones discussed in those posts.